# Different strategies to mentioning the need for negotiating a faculty position in the US

Tags: united-states, job-search, email, negotiation, contract

Today I received a written offer from a great US department in my field (Biology) and still did not reply to the email. I want to start negotiations about a few points in that offer, but I need also a few days to gather some relevant professional and personal information (I still have time before their deadline expires). Also, there is a second offer I am waiting for (from a similarly good US university in my field).

What I don't understand and can´t find clear insights about, is the following:

1. in my reply to the email containing the offer that already arrived, should I:

   - just thank them, show my enthusiasm, say I will analyse it and gather some more info before getting back to them - and then later in a separate email ask if I could have a call to clarify/discuss the offer;
   - should I thank them, show my enthusiasm and already ask if we could have a call to clarify/discuss a few points of the offer (and just mention which points in the call);
   - or should I thank them, show my enthusiasm and already mention via email the points I want to negotiate?
2. at which stage should I mention that I do have an imminent second offer? Because I already know I will have such second offer (including the approximate value of the salary proposed in that second offer); I am just waiting for the written version of it.

Answer (score 1):

I would thank them for the offer, say that you are extremely excited about the prospect of joining their department, but would like to have a bit more time to consider. I would not bring up any concrete issues immediately, nor mention any other offers unless you have something in writing. You can absolutely negotiate more, and your position would be much better once you know what offers you have lined up.

Comment: I see your point, but I still do have a reasonable amount of time to consider. I mean, before their deadline expires. I just thought I should immediately reply to their email at least to thank for the offer.

Comment: Yes, absolutely you should - that's the first statement in my answer.